# Uncoupled projections.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have troubles understanding this sentence from book Linear Algebra and its Application by Prof.Gilbert Strang.

> The hard part of least squares disappears when vectors are
>   orthonormal. The projections onto the axes are **uncoupled**, and p is
>   the sum $p=(q_1^T b)q_1+···+(q_n^T b)q_n$. We emphasize that those
>   projections do...

In particular, i don't understand what word **uncoupled** mean in this case. I understand that in case of orthonormal basis projection simplifies to $QQ^T$ and it is not invertible procedure. As i can see it pieces of b lay down on corresponding parts of basis and in the same time scaled by this basis vectors, some pieces of b are lost because we reduce dimensionality (otherwise $P=I$). But what parts of b or P or Q coupled here? I don't understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it’s another way of saying that the *orthogonal* projections onto the axes are independent of each other when the axes are orthogonal: varying the length of the component of $b$ along one axis doesn’t affect its components along any other axis. If basis vectors aren’t orthogonal, there’s “cross talk” between them and the projection of $b$ onto one vector can pick up some of the components of $b$ in other directions. I emphasize *orthogonal* here because it’s possible to find uncoupled projections for *any* basis; it’s just that they won’t necessarily be orthogonal projections (as defined by the inner product $(a,b)=b^Ta$).

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882061/265466) for a more detailed explanation, including diagrams, in $\mathbb R^2$.