# Projection of a vector onto a row space using formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

> > $v =\left [ \begin{matrix}
> >     1 \\
> >     2 \\
> >     3 \\
> >     4 \\
> >    \end{matrix} \right ]
> > $
> >     $
> > A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
> >     1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
> >     2 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
> >    \end{matrix} \right ]
> > $
> >     Find projection of $v$ onto $RowA$

$A$~$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ So $basis$ of $RowA$ is {$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    2 \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ ,$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$}.
$U=RowA$
$Proj_uv=(v.u_1/u_1^2)u_1+(v.u_2/u_2^2)u_2=$ $\left [ \begin{matrix}
    4 \\
    8 \\
    11.5 \\
    11.5 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$
[image]
But this is wrong, why?
Also, I used projection matrix $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and got the correct answer $\left [ \begin{matrix}
    5/2 \\
    5/2 \\
    5/2 \\
    5/2 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$, but this is too complicated to use in exam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the foot of the perpendicular from the points $Q(1,2,3,4)$ on the plane generated by $A(1,1,0,0), B(1,0,1,0), C(0,1,1,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399640/determine-the-foot-of-the-perpendicular-from-the-points-q1-2-3-4-on-the-plan)

Answer (score 1):

Because the basis is not orthogonal. To use the formula, apply Gram-Schmidt process to find a orthogonal basis.