# Finding the orthogonal projection $c'$ of $c$ on a plane that is spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We have two non-parallell vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ in three dimensional space, together with an arbitrary vector $\vec{c}$. I want to find the orthogonal projection $\vec{c'}$ of $\vec{c}$ on the plane that is spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, where $\vec{c'}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

I have tried to approach this problem in a couple of ways.

My first thought was to project c onto the normal vector, $\vec{n}$, of the plane and then take $\vec{c}-proj_{n}\ \vec{c}$ which would give us a vector in the plane, i.e the projection $\vec{c'}$ of $\vec{c}$ onto the plane. However, with this approach, I cannot rewrite it as a linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Another approach I have used is project $\vec{c}$ onto $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, respectively, and then add them together. With this approach I get it as a linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, but this is not the right answer.

Any help and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with “the projection”? Do you mean the *orthogonal* projection?

Comment: The projection of c, that lies in the plane that is spanned by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That occurs for *every* projection and there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Yes, I meant the orthogonal projection.

Comment: Then edit your question and add that hypothesis to it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882061/265466 for an illustration of why you can’t simply add up the individual projections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are non-parallel, you can write
$$\vec{c}' = p \vec{a} + q \vec{b}.$$
And since $\vec{c} - \vec{c}'$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$,
$$\vec{c} - \vec{c}' = r \vec{a} \times \vec{b}$$
for some $r$.  Thus,
$$\vec{c} = p \vec{a} + q \vec{b} + r \vec{a} \times \vec{b}.$$

You can take the dot product with $\vec{a}$, to get
$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} = p (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}) + q (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}).$$
You can also take the dot product with $\vec{b}$, to get
$$\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} = p (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) + q (\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b}).$$
You can then solve the linear system to get $p$ and $q$, which gives you $\vec{c}'$.