# What does inverse of a matrix that is the transpose of a matrix times itself mean in linear regression?

Tags: matrices, inverse, linear-regression, transpose

What does the below expression mean when computing linear regression coefficients,residual standard error,etc...

$(AA^{\rm T})^{-1}$

Like coefficients are calculated through:

$(AA^{\rm T})^{-1}A^{\rm T}y$

where 
A:feature matrix
y: response variable

Comment: What do you mean what does it mean?

Comment: @copper.hat what does it denote? I edited the question and added some stuff to clear it up

Comment: Why does it have to “mean” anything?

Comment: @amd It may or may not I just was wondering what it signifies so I asked

Comment: It should be $(A^TA)^{-1}$ instead of $(AA^T)^{-1}$, no? That would be the usual formula when computing a least-squares approximation for $Ax=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you really meant to write $(A^TA)^{-1}$ instead of $(AA^T)^{-1}$. The former is the usual expression that appears in the least-squares approximation for a solution to $Ax=y$. The expression $A^TA$ is called the [*Gram matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of $A$ and turns up in many contexts. Its entries are the pairwise dot products of the columns of $A$. It is invertible iff those columns are linearly independent.

In this context, it turns up because we are essentially computing the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the column space of $A$. (Why? Because $A\hat x=\hat y$ can only have a solution when $\hat y$ is in $A$’s column space.) The complete expression for this projection is $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$; without the leading $A$ factor, what you end up with is the coordinates of this projection relative to the $A$-basis. Comparing this to the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto a single vector $a$, namely ${aa^T\over a^Ta}y = a(a^Ta)^{-1}a^Ty$, we can see that the Gram matrix of $A$ plays an analogous role to the normalizing factor $a^Ta$ (which is just the dot product of $a$ with itself). When projecting onto a subspace that has dimension greater than one, though, there’s more to do than simply normalize the columns of $A$. We also need to deal with the “crosstalk” between basis vectors when they’re not orthogonal. (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882061/265466) for more details of what happens when the basis vectors aren’t orthogonal.) The Gram matrix of $A$ encodes both the norms of the basis vectors and how projections onto them overlap. Inverting this matrix sorts all of this out—for me still somewhat magically, to be honest.